# mod_rewrite in httpd.conf not working (but does in .htaccess)

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a very similar setup on 2 different servers (the working one is a Plesk install on Centos 6, the other is pretty plain LAMP setup on Centos 6) and im having an issue with mod_rewrite on the plain LAMP server.

I have compared the httpd.conf (and associated includes) on both servers and both are (for all intents and purposes) the same.

On the plesk server i have the following in my httpd.conf file which redirects http://stats.domain.com to http://www.domain.com/webstat/ and this works a treat;

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName stats
 ServerAlias stats.*
 UseCanonicalName Off
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} stats\.(.*) [NC]
 RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.%1/webstat/ [L,R=301]
</VirtualHost>
```

On the LAMP server i have the following in my httpd.conf file which is supposed to redirect http://stats.domain.com to http://www.domain.com/awstats/awstats.pl?config=domain.com

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName stats
 ServerAlias stats.* 
 UseCanonicalName Off
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} stats\.(.*) [NC]
 RewriteRule ^$ http://www.%1/awstats/awstats.pl?config=%1 [L,R=301]
</VirtualHost>
```

This is not working when in the httpd.conf file though. If i add stats.domain.com as virtualhost with full documentroot, etc and then add the same rewrite to .htaccess within that documentroot the redirect works fine.

If i enable rewrite logging then i can see the .htaccess version being worked through, but nothing from the httpd.conf. I cannot for the life of me work out what is wrong/missing :(

Answer (score 0):

The rewrite rule for your LAMP server is just putting in domain.com.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} stats\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://%1/awstats/awstats.pl?config=%1 [L,R=301]
```

Your comment above says it should be www, more like the first rule.

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.%1/awstats/awstats.pl?config=%1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Unfortunately thats not it, as each virtual host is configured both with and without the www. subdomain prefix. I've updated the post above to correct this :)